# bluemix packaged server deployment: subsequent deployments

Tags: eclipse, deployment, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud-tools

I have an application that was pushed to the Liberty runtime via the packaged server deployment method. In the future, if I make changes to my code without having to change my server.xml, do I still have to build a package and deploy the same way? Or can I just Commit and Push my changes from Eclipse or DevOps straight into Bluemix?

Answer (score 1):

you still have to push your application using the packaged server deployment method, because even if the push action uploads only what needs to be updated, it makes a full restaging once the upload is completed.
By this way, if you push only your application files without using the packaged server deployment method, it will use its server.xml template overwriting all your previous customizations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix you can take advantage of incremental publishing support by putting your packaged server in development mode. Right click on your packaged server and select Enable Development Mode. Once enabled, you can make changes to applications that are deployed on the packaged server and then once you are finished with the changes, right click on the Bluemix server and select Publish. No re-push is required and only changed files will be copied over to the Bluemix server saving a lot of time. See the following for more details: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_9.5.0/com.ibm.etools.iwd.doc/topics/tincrementalpublish.html. As you mentioned, if you change the server configuration (server.xml) then you will need to re-push the packaged server.  Incremental publishing is supported for applications deployed directly to Liberty on Bluemix as well.